# Activation Error

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

So, I deleted my profile in the folder "Profiles" in the Documents directory to try to see I could log in with a different account. I logged into the other account to find that it does not have an activated copy of the game. Therefore, I cancelled it and it brought me to a login screen. I try to log into to my "main" account (the account with the activated copy) and it gave me the activation screen (pictured below). What do I do to fix this?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some people reported that changing the system date by a few months, launching the game, quitting the game, changing the date back, and relaunching the game fixed this issue for them.

https://steamcommunity.com/app/271590/discussions/0/405694115210006486/
https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203639797-Activated-GTA-V-PC-on-RSC-website-but-launcher-wants-me-to-activate-again-